# Yii CGridView how to access id for each column

Tags: php, yii

I am using a CGridView with CActiveDataProvider. Everything works fine however now I have a need to show a custom button depending upon the id of the row.

I can add the button and get it to work as well however I cannot customise the image according to the row id. 
I can see from examples that when creating url I can access the id of row by calling $data->id however when I try to do that for imageURL it does not work. My code is below:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
            'filter'=>$model,
            'columns'=>array(
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    'desc',
                    'created',
                    array(
                            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                            'header'=>'Active State',
                            'template'=>'{rank}',
                            'buttons'=>array(
                                    'rank'=>array(
                                            'label'=>'Rank',                                                
                                            'imageUrl'=>$this->getRank($data->id),
                                            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("users/updateRank", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                                            'options'=>array(
                                                    'ajax'=>array(
                                                            'type'=>'POST',
                                                            'url'=>"js:$(this).attr('href')",                                                               
                                                    ),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                            ),                      
                    ),                      
            ),
    ));
```

Image URL calls a function in my controller which returns a url to the image. However I cannot pass the id of the current record user is clicking upon and I always get the default image back. 
If I use $data->id I get an error that data does not exist. 
If I use $this->id it is referring to the controller and I get the controller id. Anyway I can get the id of the row and pass it over to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing single quotes:

```
'imageUrl'=>'$this->getRank($data->id)',
```

is a step forward (probably you need to do something more to get your custom function work this way)

In CGridView, any php code that you want to run independently for each row, must be in quotes - if you use 'naked' php, it would be calculated only once and then the value will be same for each row.

Comment: if i add quotes the imageurl simply becomes '$this->getRank($data->id)' However if i leave them out the function does get called but I don;t know how to pass the variable. I take your point about quotes but it is not working.

Comment: Ok, sorry - now I see it's inside the 'buttons' array. The manual says, there must be an image url (not php expression), so it seems, it's not possible to use CButtonColumn this way e g there can't be different images for same button (unless you write an extension that 'corrects' it).

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail

Comment: Thanks kraabus, I went through the documentation again and you are right, it is set to string rather than php expression. So instead I have used a CDataColumn whose value atribute is call to my  function which returns the complete content to the column i.e. image with the correct link. Thanks. Will post the complete solution tomorrow.

Comment: have marked it as an answer, for others with such a problem please read all the comments. Comments from Kraabus pointed out something that I had missed in the documentation. See my edited code below. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Please see the comments above. What I was trying to do was not possible through CButtonColumn. 
Instead I am now using a CDataColumn.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
                'id',
                'name',
                'desc',
                'created',
                array(
                'class'=>'CDataColumn',
                'header'=>'Active State',                                           
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'getStatus("$data->id")',
            ),                      
        ),
));
```

getStatus returns content for this column which contains a link (ajaxLink) with first parameter as an image.

```
function getStatus($id)
{
    $imagePath="";
    ......... do your check and figure out the image you want to use

    $content ="<div align='middle'>".CHtml::ajaxLink(CHtml::image($imagePath,'Rank', array('title'=>'Rank')),CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('user/rank', 'id'=>$id)), array('type'=>'POST'))."</div>";


    return $content;
}
```